# While reloading the tableview Assertion failure is happening?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uitableview

**Error i am getting:**

```
Assertion failure in -[UITableView _endCellAnimationsWithContext:], /SourceCache/UIKit/UIKit-3347.44.2.2/UITableView.m:1326
2015-10-26 11:38:49.473 huwai[1784:684487] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'attempt to delete row 0 from section 1, but there are only 1 sections before the update'
*** First throw call stack:
(0x2a94f0d7 0x390cec77 0x2a94efad 0x2b64fbc9 0x2e1771d7 0xe865f 0xe61db 0x2e12d9ef 0x2dfdcb1d 0x2e3f6811 0x2dfa5ad5 0x2dfa3a4f 0x2dfdaeed 0x2dfda7dd 0x2dfb09b5 0x2e2270ff 0x2dfaf3b7 0x2a91500f 0x2a914423 0x2a912aa1 0x2a85e6d1 0x2a85e4e3 0x321fa1a9 0x2e010445 0x11f44d 0x3969caaf)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
```

1. I am using third party tableview (i.e)TQMultistageTableView.

2.when this error occurs means ,i am deleting values from array and again reloading the table view ,at the particular time error as happening not all the time some times its happening.

**This is my Code**

I am crating third party table view here

```
  -(void)viewWillLayoutSubviews
    {

        if([[UIDevice currentDevice].model hasPrefix:@"iPad"])
        {
            self.mTableView = [[TQMultistageTableView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width,self.viewsub.frame.size.height)];
        }
        else if([[UIDevice currentDevice].model hasPrefix:@"iPhone"])
        {
            self.mTableView =[[TQMultistageTableView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.viewsub.frame.size.width,self.viewsub.frame.size.height)];
        }
        self.mTableView.delegate = self;
        self.mTableView.dataSource = self;
        self.mTableView.clipsToBounds=YES;
        self.mTableView.tableView.clipsToBounds=YES;



    }

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(TQMultistageTableView *)tableView
{

    return [arrOrder count];
}

- (NSInteger)mTableView:(TQMultistageTableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{

    return 1;
}
#pragma mark row
- (UITableViewCell *)mTableView:(TQMultistageTableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{



    ServiceChargeCell *cell;
  cell  = [[ServiceChargeCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:@"cell" forIndexPath:indexPath];
    NSLog(@"inside charge screen product array%@",arrOrder);
    NSInteger order=[productid integerValue];
    NSMutableDictionary *dic=[flow.dicOrder objectForKey:@(order)];
    cell.lblname.textColor=[UIColor whiteColor];
    cell.lblname.text=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[dic objectForKey:@"description"]];
    NSLog(@"this is lable name=%@",[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[dic objectForKey:@"description"]]);
    NSLog(@"this is from label=%@",cell.lblname.text);

    return cell;



}
- (UIView *)mTableView:(TQMultistageTableView *)tableView openCellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UIView *view = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, tableView.bounds.size.width, tableView.bounds.size.width)];
    view.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:187/255.0 green:206/255.0 blue:190/255.0 alpha:1];;
    return view;

}

#pragma mark - Table view delegate

- (CGFloat)mTableView:(TQMultistageTableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{


    if([[UIDevice currentDevice].model hasPrefix:@"iPhone"])
    {
        return 40;
    }
    else
    {
        return 80;
    }
}
- (CGFloat)mTableView:(TQMultistageTableView *)tableView heightForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
{

    if([[UIDevice currentDevice].model hasPrefix:@"iPhone"])
    {
        return 50;
    }
    else
    {
        return 50;
    }
}
```

**in my header view i have button while that button click action some datas are removing and again i am reloading the table view here.**

```
-(void)btnClick:(UIButton *)click
{
    if(click.selected==NO)
    {
        NSString *tag=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%lu",(long)click.tag];
        int key=[tag intValue];
        NSMutableDictionary *dic=[flow.dicOrder objectForKey:@(key)];
        [flow removeOrder:dic];




    }
    [self.mTableView.tableView reloadData];



}
```

Why this kind of error happen on tableview reloading?, please any body help me to over come from this problem

Comment: i think you have didn't update your data source correctly

Comment: @MohamadFarhand i am just reloading the tableview ,how to update the data source...

Comment: A reloadData should definitely not crash the tableView. I'm pretty sure it's the third party TableView doing some kind of deletion just after the data has been updated.

Comment: @mbo42 correct. but how to do that i don't know

Comment: can u use Exeption breakpoint to find the problem ?

Comment: @MohamadFarhand no its only happens some times so i cant get it

Comment: do you define your `arrOrder` as strong property?

Comment: @KishoreKumarI am also facing the same problem with TQMultistageTableView library, how you have resolved this issue?

Comment: @AnandGautam  is your problem solved

Comment: @KishoreKumarYes.. now I have resolved the problem. Waiting for tester feedback :)

Comment: :) happy too @AnandGautam

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Predefined method is placed in tqmultistage tableview , just call this method is enough....

```
- (void)reloadData
{
    self.isReusableCell = NO;
    self.selectIndexPathIsOpen = NO;
    self.selectIndexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:-1 inSection:-1];
    self.selectOldIndexPathIsOpen = NO;
    self.selectOldIndexPath = nil;
    [self.tableView reloadData];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I looked into TQMultistageTableView, and apparently when tapping the headerView, it contains logic for deleting or inserting sections. I'm not sure how this third party thing works, but it seems like after you modify your data, it the third party tableView gets some kind of data missmatch, and it tries to delete a row that does not exist.

Comment: Thanks for your answer ,i think so but is there any way to use begin and end updates of tableview.

Comment: I assume you don't really want the tableView to do any kinds of inserts or deletes while you are manually updating your data. The TQMultistageTableView has a Tap Gesture Recognizer attached to its view, and what you could do is to check if "tableViewHeaderTouchUpInside" is being called in TQMultistageTableView when you are pressing that button. In that case, you'll want to find a way to disable this while you are pressing your button.

Comment: but the button functionality working properly,and some data i am displaying under the header view when its tapped .@mbo42 ,any possible helps?? please help me.

Comment: I'm afraid I'm not familiar with TQMultistageTableView. Add an NSLog inside the "tableViewHeaderTouchUpInside" method for TQMultistageTableView and check if it's being called at the same time as you press your button. If that's the case, you need to disable/ignore that tapRecognizer when your own button has been tapped. You don't want the tableView to interfere with it's own inserts/deletions while you are updating and reloading your data

Comment: now i am verified all of the methods in tqmultistage tableview it have update method ,if i use that no error occurs :)

Comment: Glad to be of help! Maybe you could add your own answer explaining how you solved this issue for future visitors :).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/93336/discussion-between-kishore-kumar-and-mbo42).